# JBoss Seam training

Tags: seam

I'm trying to find a training for JBoss Seam framework for my company, but the only one that I found is the one provided by JBoss themselves, which unfortunately have been already cancelled a few times because lack of needed participants, something not very encouraging.

Does anyone know about any other company that provides this kind of training (if possible in Europe)? Am I missing something or it seems like Seam is not very popular?

Thanks

Comment: This is wrong place to ask this question. please try it at [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). Closing it

Comment: @Jigar It would be possible to reopen it, I posted it in programmers stackexchange but they closed it because of being "too localized"...

Comment: It is still in open state here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our company offers Seam training. In fact, I am one of the instructors. The JBoss Seam material is very old and outdated. Trust me, as a former instructor for the JBoss Seam courses, (we where JBoss partners), you don't wan't to take that course.

Take a look [here](https://training.redpill-linpro.com/category/jboss/#seam-basic) for more information.

Comment: Hello Shervin, thanks for your answer, but I got it wrong or you are not recommending to take the courses from your own company? Anyway, the only training I could find is the official from JBoss https://www.redhat.com/courses/jb311_jboss_seam_application_development/

Comment: You are wrong. I mean that the offical JBoss seam courses are not recommended. Our courses are up 2 date.

Comment: Hi again Shervin, I've been checking the courses, and from outside, I have to say that the official one looks more updated, there is even a section for Seam 3

Comment: Yes it seems you are correct. They have updated the course finally. I have no knowledge of that specific course, so I cannot say which is better.